# Waiting in a Jetty thread

Tags: spring-boot, jetty

In my `Spring Boot` web app I make two calls to a legacy system. When the first call returns I need to wait some time before making the second call.

I don't want to `sleep` in my thread, but to return it to the pool until some time has passed and I can make the second call.

So the question is: How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`javax.servlet.AsyncContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html), it exists for just this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be as follows:

```java
@GetMapping("/fubar")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> fubar() {
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    scheduledExecutor.schedule(() -> {
        // do some useful stuff here
        result.setResult("Hello World");
    }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return output;
}
```

It works like this:

1. You define a *scheduled executor* bean and inject it in your controller
2. In the endpoint where you want a delay you submit a runnable which will be executed after a certain delay and will set a result to the `DeferredResult` instance
3. Despite returning the `DeferredResult` instance straight away, the client will wait until the delay has passed before receiving the result.

**NB!** All the work will happen in the thread pool that belongs to the scheduled executor, not in the common pool. So it needs to be configured accordingly.